# Idiomatic way of converting string of key value pairs to a JSON string (Scala)

Tags: json, scala, key-value

I'm trying to convert a string of key value pairs to a JSON string. The only thing I know about the string of KV pairs is the format of the string i.e. space seperated, comma seperated etc.. For e.g. I don't control over the number or type of the keys coming in as input.

Here is what I came up with and wanted to see if this approach looks OK / awesome / awkward. Would appreciate if there is better alternative than this.

```
INPUT : clientIp="1.1.1.1" identifier="a.b.c" key1=10 key2="v3"

final val KV_PATTERN = "(\"[^\"]*\"|[^,\\\"\\s]*)=(\"[^\"]*\"|[^,\\\"\\s]*)".r

val cMap = KV_PATTERN.findAllMatchIn(inputString).map(m => (m.group(1).trim(), m.group(2).trim())).toMap

val json = cMap.map { case (key, value) => if (!key.startsWith("\"")) s""""$key"""" + ":" + value else s"$key:$value" }.mkString("{", ",", "}")`

OUTPUT: {"clientIp":"1.1.1.1","identifier":"a.b.c","key1":10,"key2":"v3"}
```

Comment: All you did is replace spaces with comas, and put a pair of braces around the string. Just saying ... `s"{${s.replaceAll(" ", ",")}}"`.  BTW, this isn't really valid json.

Comment: Dima - of course in your case...there are lot of other cases you miss..for e.g. .all the keys needs to be quoted in JSON..replace key value seperator with : Also to make it generic, with the regex pattern approach I can just change it as per the input format. With the my approach, I verified it does turn out to be a valid JSON

Comment: it's not "my case", it's _your_ case. The case you asked about.
Sure, if you right a different regular expression, it'll be a different case ... You could right different scala code, for a different case too. Some people prefer writing code in scala, others like regex more ... question of taste, I guess. And no, what you quoted in your question is not valid json.

Comment: Dima: if you're interesting more in nitpicking than providing a solution, I edited minor typos in my input and output. All I'm looking here is better solution than mine, basically key value pairs to JSON.. that's it..not rants.  Working code beats arguments.

Comment: You are using the sample output as the specification of the expected result. There is nothing short CH thing as "minor typo". Anyway, I still don't see much that your code is doing that mine does not. Quoting the keys?

Answer (score 2):

```
"{"+ inputString.split(" ").map{case i => val t = i.split("="); s""""${t(0).replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")}": ${t(1)}"""}.mkString(",") + "}"
```

Maybe this is more cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. +1.. this works too. do you think using it via regex and map would be more expensive ?